# array results not getting in proper format

Tags: php, arrays, soap-client

I got the following parameters as a response from SOAP client. But i want to display this result in plain and proper format without displaying Array or any brackets.

Code:

```
if($parameter['aktion'] == 'login') 
{ 
    while ($val = current(getVehicleValuation())) 
    {
        echo key(getVehicleValuation()).' '.$val.'<br>';
        next(getVehicleValuation());
    }   
}

function getVehicleValuation()
{
$return = array(
                                        'SchwackeCode' => $result->vehicle->SchwackeCode,
                                        'WE_Number'    => $result->vehicle->WE_Number,
                                        'HSN'                => $result->vehicle->HSN, 
                                        'TSN'                => $result->vehicle->TSN,
                                        'VIN'                => $result->vehicle->Ident_Number,
                                        'WE_Number'      => $result->vehicle->WE_Number                                     
                                );
    return $return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my function **printMyArray($array)** to print your array with keys.

```
<?php
    $array=array(
    'test1' => 'firstvalue',
    'test2' => 'secondvalue'
    );

    printMyArray($array);


    function printMyArray ($array)
    {
            while ($val = current($array)) {
                echo key($array).' '.$val.'<br>';
                next($array);
            }
    }
?>
```

Like the for loop can be converted to while loop, similarly a foreach loop can be converted to while loop like this.

**Edit:**
You have not implemented it correctly. You can't use **getVehicleValuation()** like that in the loop.
Change your code to this:

```
if($parameter['aktion'] == 'login') 
{ 
    $returned_array=getVehicleValuation();
    while ($val = current($returned_array)) 
    {
        echo key($returned_array).' '.$val.'<br>';
        next($returned_array);
    }   
}
```

Comment: sorry u did not understood my question. Please check the updated question..i just want to remove Array and [] from my output results.. I just want plain output format to display..

Comment: Yes you want to remove square brackets and Array(), right? Just use my function, it will do that.

Comment: ohh i tried but its getting error ..and its also looking complicated because i have different function already which i am using and crating another function for just 1 print statement u think its a right idea ?...

Comment: What error is it giving? Please post the full code where you have put this function and used it?

Comment: I have given you the solution. Check my post above.

Comment: thanks its running now properly...and i have question will it work for more than 1 value ? As my result are coming from Soap Client i am geting only 1 vehicle result but what if there are more than 1 vehicles ...so will this your result loops for that ?

Comment: for a double dimensional array you will have to nest the loops